# Apache pig how to parse a tuple to extract columns

Tags: tuples

In Apache pig, how to parse a tuple to extract columns

```
{grp::group: (dt: chararray,ord_id: int),long,grp1::group: (chararray,ord_id1: int),double,l

group,dt,ord_id,long,double
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use FLATTEN to do so.